# Adding Dynamic TextBoxes to Dynamically added Panels

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

Windows Forms, VS 2012, VB.NET

I've tried some code but somehow the dang Textboxes aren't being place inside the panels, i can only assume that im not actually placing them inside the panel, anyone able give me some code to fix my issue ?

Sample code :

```
 For Each name As String In li
                Dim Answer As String() = AnsStrPerItem(i).Split(",")
                'addField(NameOfPanel,Width,Height,LocationX,LocationY,color White=white else gray)
                'addPanel("Panel" & i.ToString, 1100, 529, 3, (12 + (i * 89)), "White")
                'addField(NameOfButton,TextOfButton,Width,Height,LocationX,LocationY,readonly 0 = true)
                addField("Q" & i.ToString, name.ToString, 533, 64, 14, (69 + (i * 89)), 0)
                addField("A" & i.ToString, Answer(1), 553, 64, 597, (69 + (i * 89)), 1)
                i += 1
            Next
```

and the code to actually add the panel / txtbox

```
Public Function addPanel(ByVal NameOfPanel As String, ByVal Width As Integer, ByVal Height As Integer, ByVal LocationX As Integer, ByVal LocationY As Integer, ByVal color As String)

    '------------------------ADDING FIELDS INTO FORM TO SIMULATE A DATAREPEATER

    'INSTANTIATE CONTROL
    Dim Panel As System.Windows.Forms.Panel

    'CREATE CONTROL
    Panel = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()

    'SET TEXT PROPERTIES
    Panel.Name = NameOfPanel
    Panel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(Width, Height)
    Panel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(LocationX, LocationY)

    If color = "White" Then Panel.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White Else Panel.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGray

    'ADD CONTROL TO FORM1'S COLLECTION
    Form1.Panel5.Controls.Add(Panel)

    Return Nothing

End Function

Public Function addField(ByVal NameOfButton As String, ByVal TextOfButton As String, ByVal Width As Integer, ByVal Height As Integer, ByVal LocationX As Integer, ByVal LocationY As Integer, ByVal ro As Integer)

    '------------------------ADDING FIELDS INTO FORM TO SIMULATE A DATAREPEATER

    'INSTANTIATE CONTROL
    Dim txtb As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

    'CREATE CONTROL
    txtb = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()

    'SET TEXT PROPERTIES
    txtb.Name = NameOfButton
    txtb.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(Width, Height)
    txtb.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(LocationX, LocationY)
    txtb.Text = TextOfButton
    txtb.Multiline = True
    Dim myfont As New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16, FontStyle.Regular)
    txtb.Font = myfont
    If ro = 0 Then txtb.ReadOnly = True

    'ADD CONTROL TO FORM1'S COLLECTION
    Form1.Panel5.Controls.Add(txtb)

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding controls

```
For Each name As String In li
                'addField(NameOfPanel,Width,Height,LocationX,LocationY,color White=white else gray)
                If ((i Mod 2) = 0) Then
                    addPanel("pQna" & i.ToString, 1138, 100, 3, (i * 89), "Lgray")
                Else
                    addPanel("pQna" & i.ToString, 1138, 100, 3, (i * 89), "White")
                End If
                'addField(NameOfButton,TextOfButton,Width,Height,LocationX,LocationY,readonly 0 = true)
                addField("Q" & i.ToString, name.ToString, 533, 64, 14, 14, 0, i)
                addField("A" & i.ToString, "", 553, 64, 597, 14, 1, i)
                i += 1
            Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

adding panels

```
Public Function addPanel(ByVal NameOfPanel As String, ByVal Width As Integer, ByVal Height As Integer, ByVal LocationX As Integer, ByVal LocationY As Integer, ByVal color As String)

    '------------------------ADDING FIELDS INTO FORM TO SIMULATE A DATAREPEATER

    'INSTANTIATE CONTROL
    Dim Panel As System.Windows.Forms.Panel

    'CREATE CONTROL
    Panel = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()

    'SET TEXT PROPERTIES
    Panel.Name = NameOfPanel
    Panel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(Width, Height)
    Panel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(LocationX, LocationY)

    If color = "White" Then Panel.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White Else Panel.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGray

    'ADD CONTROL TO FORM1'S COLLECTION
    Form1.pQnA.Controls.Add(Panel)

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

adding textboxes within the panel

```
Public Function addField(ByVal NameOfButton As String, ByVal TextOfButton As String, ByVal Width As Integer, ByVal Height As Integer, ByVal LocationX As Integer, ByVal LocationY As Integer, ByVal ro As Integer, ByVal i As Integer)
    '-----------------------FINDING PANEL

    For Each pnl As Control In Form1.pQnA.Controls
        If TypeOf pnl Is Panel Then
            Dim var As String = pnl.Name.ToString
            If pnl.Name.Equals("pQna" & i.ToString) Then


                '------------------------ADDING FIELDS INTO FORM TO SIMULATE A DATAREPEATER

                'INSTANTIATE CONTROL
                Dim txtb As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

                'CREATE CONTROL
                txtb = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()

                'SET TEXT PROPERTIES
                txtb.Name = NameOfButton
                txtb.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(Width, Height)
                txtb.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(LocationX, LocationY)
                txtb.Text = TextOfButton
                txtb.Multiline = True
                Dim myfont As New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16, FontStyle.Regular)
                txtb.Font = myfont
                If ro = 0 Then txtb.ReadOnly = True

                'ADD CONTROL TO FORM1'S COLLECTION
                'Form1.pQnA.Controls.Add(txtb)
                DirectCast(pnl, Panel).Controls.Add(txtb)

            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You might need to clarify a bit.  In the first function, you're adding a panel to a panel.  In the second function your adding a textbox to the parent panel.  If the child panel is over top of the textbox it is probably hiding it. If you want the textbox added to the child panel something like this should work:

```
Form1.Panel5.Controls(Form1.Panel5.Controls.IndexOfKey(NameOfPanel)).Controls.Add(txtb)
```

Comment: sorry about that, and also heres the answer below - the problem was that i had to aparanelty 'find' the panel with a for each loop through my controls and then cast them to the panel...  thanks for the answer and sry for not specifying

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub ReInitializeComponent()

   Me.TextBoxUserId = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()

   Me.TextBoxUserId.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(54, 1)

   Me.TextBoxUserId.Name = "TextBoxUserId"

   Me.TextBoxUserId.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(149, 20)

   Me.TextBoxUserId.TabIndex = 13

   Me.TextBoxUserId.Text = ""

end sub
```